# How to correctly configure APIGateway for CORS using the CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have an API provided by AWS ApiGateway, backed by an AWS Lambda function and provisioned using the CDK. The API has been configured with default CORS settings:

```
const api = new apiGateway.RestApi(this, "comments-api", {
  defaultCorsPreflightOptions: { allowOrigins: apiGateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS }
})

const comments = api.root.addResource("comments")

const comment = comments.addResource("{post_slug}")

comment.addMethod("GET", new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(listCommentsFunction))
```

This appears to provide only *part* of the CORS configuration for my API.

- It provides a response to an `OPTIONS` request with the appropriate CORS related headers but
- It seems it does NOT hydrate the response to a request to `GET <api>/comments/{post_slug}` with the appropriate CORS headers

This makes the `CORS` configuration options in the CDK construct *not particularly useful* - since it seems more sensible for me to ignore that setting and instead *manually* configure an OPTIONS response from my Lambda, by changing it to this:

```
const api = new apiGateway.RestApi(this, "comments-api")

const comments = api.root.addResource("comments")
const comment = comments.addResource("{post_slug}")

comment.addMethod("GET", new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(listCommentsFunction))
comment.addMethod("OPTIONS", new apiGateway.LambdaIntegration(listCommentsFunction))
```

And then ensuring that my lambda always responds with the correct headers. If I *don't* do this, then I'm hydrating my responses with CORS headers using *two* different mechanisms; CDK stack configuration and explicit handler logic. This feels like a smell.

I'm wondering for this reason if I'm misconfiguring something and there is a way to use the CDK to configure the response to be correctly hydrated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDK generated code for the `OPTIONS` method is using response overrides - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html

This option is not available in the lambda proxy integration, which you are using for the GET method. I did not found indeed any other option than to calculate the CORS headers on the lambda source code level.

*P.S.: I wrote https://milangatyas.com/Blog/Detail/14/setup-cors-for-amazon-api-gateway-via-aws-cdk where you can get more detailed information.*